# Salvage "What to eat" rather than close

Tags: discussion

[What foods to eat when changing from meat to vegetarian to vegan?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/407/what-foods-to-eat-when-changing-from-meat-to-vegetarian-to-vegan)

I voted to reopen even though closed as too broad. My feeling is it is a very very important, common and basic question. I posted how I construct my diet and nutrition in some detail. I suggest we do *something* to leave it open since answering the question "I want to go vegan, what should I eat?" is so fundamental.

Update: this question? https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/454/what-does-a-typical-balanced-vegan-meal-look-like-for-someone-converting-from-a

Comment: If it's closed already, don't reopen just because you feel it has potential. Edit it into a reopenable state first.

Answer (score 5):

Quote from an answer to the question

> If you are a lazy bachelor trying to get by on 15 minutes of cooking a day, you can skip the vegetable most of the time if you are meeting your micronutrient needs.

This is a good illustration of why the question is too broad imho. The OP isn't a lazy bachelor, and though some people reading the answer may be, a larger proportion will be otherwise. You say the question is fundamental, but this bit of the answer makes it seem like the author thinks their experience is the universal (I realise that's not true of course).

A good question in my opinion would be

"I'm a lazy bachelor (living in the US), and I want to go vegan; what should I eat?"

That question would help lazy USian bachelors wanting to go vegan.

But in my view it's not possible to write an answer that applies to everyone based on personal experience, because it's really something that depends on context, so as a general question it invites an endless number of opinion-based answers that visitors would have to sift through looking for something relevant to them

Answer (score 4):

But the question isn't actually "I want to go vegan, what should I eat". It includes *100% vegetarian or vegan* (which one? there's a difference) and background that indicates the OP already isn't eating any meat or dairy but doesn't give specifics on what he (or his wife) is still trying to eliminate.

Just because a question is *important* does not mean it is *answerable* within StackExchange standards; also, significance should not be an excuse to ignore possible improvements. If you envision this as a fundamental question for our site (and I agree it certainly could/should be), it needs to be well written.

Comment: http://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/454/what-does-a-typical-balanced-vegan-meal-look-like-for-someone-converting-from-a ?

Comment: There are some new/different problems with that; I've left a comment over there for you. I swear I am not trying to be a jerk with this, just attempting to define "good" Q&A for a site (within StackExchange's limitations on "good")...